# Is there a similar method for qobject_cast in pyQT?

Tags: casting, pyqt

I have a subclass of QTreeWidget, and I want to do some operation such as

```
class MyTree(QTreeWidget):
    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        super(MyTreeWidget,self).mouseMoveEvent(event)
        event = QMouseEvent(event)
```

It seems that MyTree type has changed to MyTree, I cannot call QTreeWidget method `itemAt` unless I use `super` key word like this:

```
super(MyTreeWidget,self).itemAt(event.globalPos())
```

Is there a similar method to `qobject_cast` in PyQt? I know `qobject_cast` exists in Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent of `qobject_cast` in PyQt.  If you wish to access an overridden superclass method, you must use `super`.

In C++, you can have a variable declared as a pointer to one type `QObject *` when it actually points to an object of a derived type.  For example:

```
QObject *obj = new QWidget;
```

I don't know C++ well enough to say whether methods are determined at compile time or run time.  In other words, if you then have

```
obj->someQObjectMethodOverriddenInQWidget(...);
```

then I'm not sure whether this will call the `QObject` or `QWidget` method. (I would guess that it would be the `QObject` method; it seems you want to use `qobject_cast` to cast an object to the superclass in order to call overridden superclass methods, and if this didn't happen you wouldn't be wanting to use `qobject_cast`.)

On the other hand, Python has no type information available at compile time; it relies solely on the run-time type of an object to determine which method to call.  If you have overridden a method in a subclass, and you want to call the overridden method from the superclass, you must use `super`.  On the other hand, if `MyTree` does not override `itemAt`, you should just be able to call `self.itemAt(...)`, as it will inherit `itemAt` from its superclass.